# Adding images in JSP using netbeans

Tags: jsp, netbeans

I am new to JSP and presently I am not able to display any image. I am using netbeans IDE 8.1 and have created a web project named "TestProject". I am using Apache Tomcat to test my files. Here is my directory structure:

```
Web Pages
-css(contains a few files)
-js(contains a few files)
-Image
  -kitty.jpg
  -bunny.jpg
-META INF
-WEB INF(empty)
-index.jsp
```

I have tried a number of methods to display an image in index.jsp but none have worked.

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Image/kitty.jpg" class="img-circle"  width="304" height="236" />
```

Just a minute ago, the above code worked but when I restarted netbeans, it no longer works. I have tried entering the image url in chrome and then also I am getting the same error "Failed to load resource". I typed:

```
http://localhost:8035/TestProject/Image/kitty.jpg
```

When I put the images to root directory then also it doesn't work. What should I do? Using images will be an important aspect of my project much like the previous one I did with PHP. I think something's wrong with the directory structure.

Thanks

Comment: <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Image/kitty.jpg" class="img-circle"  width="304" height="236" />
This is just one of the methods I have tried. A minute ago, it somehow worked. I restarted Netbeans and it's not working again

Comment: Post the code **in the question**.

Comment: I am unable to post the code in the question, don't know the formatting rules

Comment: You paste your code, select it, and press Ctrl-K (or the code button in the toolbar).